# Read from file and store into dict containing dict and list

Tags: python

I've searched all over the web for the answer to my question and I've used aspects of what I've learned to help me get to this point.  However, I've been unable to find the solution to get me where I need to be.

In the shortest way possible, I need to create a dictionary containing a dictionary and a list of values as read in from a file, and print the output.

I was able to do this using a statically created dictionary, but I seem to be unable to create the dictionary in the same format while reading in from a file.

Here is the code I was able to get working:

```
routers = {'fre-agg1': {'interface Te0/1/0/0': ["rate-limit input 135", "rate-limit input 136"],
                        'interface Te0/2/0/0': ["rate-limit input 135", "rate-limit input 136"]},
           'fre-agg2': {'interface Te0/3/0/0': ["rate-limit input 135", "rate-limit input 136", "rate-limit input 137"]}}

for rname in routers:
    print rname
    for iname in routers[rname]:
        print iname
        for int_config in routers[rname][iname]:
            print int_config
```

The output of this prints exactly in the format I need it to be:

```
fre-agg2
interface Te0/3/0/0
rate-limit input 135
rate-limit input 136
rate-limit input 137
fre-agg1
interface Te0/1/0/0
rate-limit input 135
rate-limit input 136
interface Te0/2/0/0
rate-limit input 135
rate-limit input 136
```

The file I am trying to read in is in a different format:

```
ama-coe:interface Loopback0
ama-coe: ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
ama-coe:interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
ama-coe: description EGM to xyz Gi2/0/1
ama-coe: ip address 10.2.1.1 255.255.255.254
ama-coe:interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
ama-coe: description EGM to abc Gi0/0/1
ama-coe: ip address 10.3.1.1 255.255.255.254
```

For this file, I'd like the output of the file as the same output shown above, with the interface configuration listed under the interface name, listed under the device name

```
ama-coe
interface Loopback0
ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
etc etc etc
```

So far, here is the code I have:

```
routers = {}

with open('cpe-interfaces-ipaddress.txt') as inputFile:
    inputData = inputFile.read().splitlines()
    for rname in inputData:
        device, stuff = rname.split(':')
        if not device in routers:
            routers[device] = None
        elif stuff == "interface":
            routers[device][None] = stuff
```

I know this code is extremely incomplete but I can't for the life of me figure out the dictionary and list structure as I did when statically creating the dict.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
routers = {}

with open('cpe-interfaces-ipaddress.txt') as inputFile:
    cur_interface = None
    for rname in inputFile:
        device, stuff = rname.strip().split(':')
        print device, stuff, cur_interface
        if not device in routers:
            routers[device] = {}

        if stuff.startswith("interface"):
            key_word, interface = stuff.split(' ')
            routers[device].setdefault(interface, [])
            cur_interface = interface
        else: # ip address
            routers[device][cur_interface].append(stuff)
```

Not knowing if this meet your need. I made an assumption that each ip address is belong to previous interface.

The way using a dictionary to organize stuff is common. You should learn some built-in methods, such as **setdefault** and **append**.

Comment: In this format, we are printing the device-name, followed by the interface, followed by stuff on each line.  The format I needed was the device name on the first line, interface on the second line, stuff on the 3rd (and later) lines, followed by the next device.  
  
`router1  
interface1  
stuff  
router2  
interface1  
stuff  
interface2  
stuff`
  
Also, I'm getting a key error on the first device that is run, whereas the rest of the lines seem to not have any issues.  I'm looking into the issue but can't promise I'll figure it out.